# Running collectstatic from Heroku runs successfully, but fails to push the files to AWS, run locally it's successful

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm trying to run a basic django app from Heroku using S3 to serve both static and media files.

When I run the server locally with `python3 manage.py collectstatic` the static files are collected and placed into a newly created /static/ folder in my S3 bucket.

When I run `heroku run python3 manage.py collectstatic` I am told that the static files have been collected and copied to /app/staticfiles (on build with collectstatic not disabled it's collected and copied to /tmp/build_[id]/staticfiles).  Nothing is added to my S3 bucket; looking at the app filestructure on Heroku there is no folder /app/staticfiles;  the app has no folder called /staticfiles; and I only have one S3 bucket, so I'm not accidentally pushing to the wrong bucket. Finally, I've quadruple checked that the dev and prod environment settings match (where appropriate).

My hunch is that `django.contrib.staticfiles` has a very strong opinion about where the static files should end up and is overriding my settings for aws (`aws_settings.py`) once in production.  Any pointers about how to resolve this, gratefully received!

settings.py

```
import os
import dj_database_url
import dotenv
import django_heroku


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(
                os.path.dirname(
                    os.path.abspath(__file__)))
dotenv_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")

if os.path.isfile(dotenv_file):
    #DEV_ENV
    dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_file)
    os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']='DEV'
    from .envsettings.dev_settings import *

elif os.getenv('TEST_ENV', None):
    #TEST_ENV
    os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']='TEST'
    from .envsettings.test_settings import *

else:
    os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']='PROD'
    from .envsettings.prod_settings import *

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'storages',
    'django_clamd',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [

    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'

#ugly hack, probably a better way
if os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']=='PROD':
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
            }
        }
    DATABASES['default'].update(dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500))
    django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

dev_settings.py

```
import os
import dotenv
SECRET_KEY='shhhh'
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myapp',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT':'',

    }
}

from .aws_settings import *
```

prod_settings.py

```
import os
from .aws_settings import *

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET', '')
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myapp.herokuapp.com',]
```

aws_settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(
            os.path.dirname(
                os.path.dirname(
                    os.path.abspath(__file__))))

#S3 settings
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', '')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME', '')
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

#static media settings
STATIC_URL = 'https://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'https://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = ('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
                       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',)
```

customstorages.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is the resolution](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/issues/25)

`django_heroku.settings(locals())` was overriding my STATIC_URL.  Replacing it with `django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)` was the main fix.

There was also the issue that my STATICFILES_DIRS contained my STATIC_ROOT (uncovered when running `python3 manage.py runserver --insecure`).